# Can 有 be used to form present perfect tense?

Tags: grammar

One meaning of 有 is "have" i.e. possess. Can 有 also be used to form the present perfect tense as in "I have looked", possibly "我有看"?

If so, then a follow-up question: what is more natural, using 有 or 过?

Comment: Yes, but it's a typical case of *translationese*, at least in China mainland. Many think *translationese* is negative.

Comment: this has come up before and answered by link to 
What does the construction 有 ＋ Verb mean? https://www.italki.com/question/200801

Comment: Only in Taiwan.

Comment: @EnricoBrasil, yeah, Taiwanese like to use 有+verb. Mainlanders perfer verb+过. Nevertheless, both can be clearly understood.

Comment: 我想了一下，“有看”和“看过”还是略微有些差别的。Scenario：老师交待学生回去要看某本书。第二天，有位学生回答不上来老师提问的关于那本书里的内容。老师问他，“我交待的书你有没有看过？”如果回答“有看过”，那表明很可能只是看了一眼，没有认真阅读。如果回答“我看过。”有点完整看过的意思，如果为了表明自己没有认真看，可以补充一句，“只不过没有好好看。”

Comment: 用“有”，不一定就是perfect tense。比如“有在看”，就是正在进行时？我也不知道英语里这种情况用什么时态，比如一本书，我最近一直在看，但此时此刻，我没有盯着它在看。

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use 有 to form present perfect tense, consider the following examples:

1. In mainland, people usually don't use 有 (to me it sounds a bit childish and made me think of a little girl.) :

   Michel: 你看过 "Pride and Prejudice" 没? Have you ever read ...

   Emily: (我)看过。 I have read it.
2. In Hong Kong or Taiwan, looks like it's frequently used (I haven't been there but in quite a lot of TV series and variety shows the celebrities often use it, friends from there may correct me if I'm wrong)

   Michel: "你有看(过) 'Pride and Prejudice' 没?"

   Emily: "(我)有看(过)啊，很好看的。" (I have read it.)

Here you can see, since you have used 有, 过 becomes optional.

As for 有 and 过, in order to form a perfect tense you should at least use one, depends on which tone do you want to use from the previous examples.

Comment: Except that this looks rather contrived (at least to the language police). The meaning is absolutely the same if 有 is removed.

Comment: Haha, I live in Hong Kong and I'm studying a Chinese course. It is just now that I found out I misused `有` and `會` (`本班列車不會載客`) in my past ~20 years writing essays.

Answer (score 2):

This is an really interesting question. It is actually a wrong usage in Taiwanese Mandarin. Since we speak a lot of Taiwanese here, the usage of adding 有 in showing past perfect is effected by Taiwanese or which called "Minnan" dialect.

In standard Chinese grammar, for example:
**I have read the book. 我讀過那本書。
---->我有讀過那本書。
Have you had dinner? 吃過飯了嗎？
---->有吃飯了嗎？**

If you get someone who can speak Minnan dialect, it will sound perfectly smooth in Minnan. However, it became an incorrect usage that used by everyone in Taiwan.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question is more complicated than a misuse in Taiwan. In Xinhua dictionary, `有` has a meaning of `yield` or `have happened`.

Consider the short sentence.

> 情况有变化。

It is a rough paraphrase to `情况变了`. `了` is, of course a perfect tense word. So could we also regard `有` here as a perfect tense word too?

Sadly, among linguists there is still controversy upon the issue. I would personally suggest `情况有变化` emits a stronger feeling of `Situations have changed` than `There are changes in situations`.

Consider another phrase

> 有辱师门

What `有` means here? The phrase does manifest a solid meaning of `have shamed masters` instead of `Something exists, which shames masters`.

The only consensus researchers have reached so far is `有` doesn't act as an auxiliary verb. The word is still a transitive verb. So you feel OK when the following word/phrase is both a verb or a noun, or is often regarded as a noun, namely a gerund. But it is weird when conditions are not met.

An idea comes to my mind that we may need a 'perfect tense' scale. From the weakest to the strongest lies `有`, `过` and `了`. Improper combinations of 'past tense' word and the following verb give strange impressions.

Besides, I would remind you `有` is more of an aspect word, rather than a tense word. It only implies perfect, not necessarily present. For instance, `情况有过变化` has a stronger meaning of `Situations had changed.` And sometimes the word's meaning is probably overrided, such as `在这几年里，情况有变化` (`Situations are changing in the past few years.`).

I'm not a professional studying Chinese. Feel free to challenge me if you have different ideas. Finally I'd like to point out language itself is a *evolving* magic, maybe one day today's misuse would become tomorrow's fashion.

Answer (score 1):

“我有看过”= “我看过” it means I have read it.
"有" emphasis that have already do something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from southern China. In my experience, 过 is used more to form present perfect tense than 有.

But sometimes people do use 有. It seems more common in Taiwan mandarin, or at least "stereotypical" Taiwan mandarin.